# Updating one-to-many relationships with Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I cannot figure out how to update related data using Razor Pages asp.net core 2.0.

In the below example, I can update the "Project" data, but I cannot see the related "Action" data (one project => many actions) on OnPostAsync().

EditModel : PageModel

```
    [BindProperty]
    public Project Project { get; set; }


    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        //THIS PART WORKS, I CAN SEE ACTIONS WITH THE PROJECT
        Project = await _context.Project.Include(a=>a.Action).SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

        if (Project == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? id)
    {
        //MODEL IS NOT RETURNING ACTIONS (One project many actions)
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        //How do I update actions?

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ProjectExists(Project.Id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

OnModelCreating:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Action>(entity =>
        {

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Project)
                .WithMany(p => p.Action)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProjectId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Action_Project");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not understood how BindProperty works. By using BindProperty for a property you ask from the framework the value of the property to be available in the view, and in case that you have an input containing the value it will go back to the property when you submit the contents of the input.

This means that even for the project object you will not get values if you do not have inputs which will host the values of the mode.

You have two options. The first option is to put inputs for all the your action items of the list which is not a good idea and the second option is to query the list from the database again after the submition of the form.

Comment: I am getting values back on both calls, OnGetAsync and OnPostAsync.  However, OnGetAsync I can see  both Project and Action values, on OnPostAsync I only see (and can update) Project.